# If response contains the word 'any' then match response contains is failing

Tags: karate

Let's say if I am having a scenario like

```
Scenario: Call a Get API and validate the response 
    Given path 'myteam' 
    When method get 
    Then status 201 
    And print response
    And match response contains { teamFeature: 'pick any feature'}
```

And my API response is

```
{
  "id": "6c0377cd-96c9-4651-bcc8-0c9a7d962bc3",
  "teamFeature": "pick any feature"
}
```

Then I am getting the error like

> example.feature:19 - javascript evaluation failed: feature'}, :1:9 Missing close quote
>   feature'}
>            ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 9

If my API response does not contain the word 'any' and I change the match statement then it is working fine. Looks like I need to escape the the word 'any' somehow.

May I know how can I escape the word 'any'?

Not sure if this is a bug in Karate.

Tried to call

```
com.intuit.karate.Match match = new com.intuit.karate.Match("pick any feature");
System.out.println(match.contains("pick any feature"));
```

And received following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript
>   evaluation failed: pick any feature, :1:5 Expected ; but found
>   any pick any feature
>        ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 5  at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:152)   at
>   com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:142)
>     at
>   com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:127)
>     at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:423)   at
>   com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:337)    at
>   com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:203)    at
>   com.intuit.karate.Match.(Match.java:67)     at
>   com.intuit.karate.Match.(Match.java:53)

Comment: looks like an issue with match step for this condition, temp workaround would be `* def expected = { teamFeature: 'pick any feature'}` and then `And match response contains expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a bug in Karate, we've opened an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/678

The workaround suggested by @BabuSekaran will work:

```
* def response = { foo: 'a any b' }
* def temp = { foo: 'a any b' }
* match response contains temp
```